# How to get methods from WMI

Tags: c#, .net, methods, wmi, system.management

**tl;dr** What should I `SELECT` instead of `*` in order to get the methods?

**More info:**

Here's an example:

```
using (var s = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM someClass"))
    foreach (var obj in s.Get())
```

**If I just ask for one property** it's not enough - I get an exception when trying `obj.InvokeMethod(...);`.

**If I ask for `*` it is enough** but I rather avoid this if possible.

I don't see any property for getting the methods (-`Disable`, `Enable`,...) in the docs for WMI classes. And if it's *not* on the list - how come `*` works? Isn't it just supposed to ask for all *of those on the list*?

**EDIT**

Someone suggested using [ManagementClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wzwcace(v=vs.110).aspx)  instead of `ManagementObjectSearcher`. Does this load all properties like `*`? (If not, that's a good answer. Though in my actual case I need a property besides the ability to call a method. And my theoretical questions remains - is `*` more than just **all**.)

Comment: WMI is pretty rough with finding what you need but this tool was really helpful for me to learn how it works. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572.

Comment: It looks like they took it down... I still have it if you want I can host it and provide a link to download.

Comment: @SamMarion Thanks. I already have the tool somewhere. (At least I think I do) but my question isn't just how to get the methods. My question is how to get them _without_ using `*`.

Comment: The tool generates code that doesn't use the star and will show you what methods are available if I remember correctly. Does it not?

Comment: Nevermind, I seem to be remembering the tool provided from Microsoft uses the * in all their queries, sorry.

Comment: @SamMarion I just tried it, and under the "Execute a Method" tab it returns a script. It's very different from code, and seems to load the whole class.

Comment: have you looked here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9ck6sf2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @styx Thanks. Perhaps I'm wrong about this, but doesn't that load the whole class like using `*`?

Comment: @ispiro, seems like it does

Answer (score 2):

As far as what the title and TL;DR are asking, methods cannot be queried via `SELECT` but you can use the [`ManagementClass.Methods` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementclass.methods) to inspect those provided by that management class.  For example, this code...

```cs
using (ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process"))
    foreach (MethodData method in processClass.Methods)
    {
        bool isStatic = method.Qualifiers
            .Cast<QualifierData>()
            .Any(qualifier => string.Equals(qualifier.Name, "Static", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        Console.WriteLine($"{method.Origin}.{method.Name}() [{(isStatic ? "static" : "instance")}]");
        if (method.InParameters != null && method.InParameters.Properties.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tInput parameters:");
            foreach (PropertyData parameterProperty in method.InParameters.Properties)
                Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{parameterProperty.Type} {parameterProperty.Name}");
        }
        if (method.OutParameters != null && method.OutParameters.Properties.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tOutput parameters:");
            foreach (PropertyData parameterProperty in method.OutParameters.Properties)
                Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{parameterProperty.Type} {parameterProperty.Name}");
        }
    }
```

...produces this output...

```
Win32_Process.Create() [static]
    Input parameters:
        String CommandLine
        String CurrentDirectory
        Object ProcessStartupInformation
    Output parameters:
        UInt32 ProcessId
        UInt32 ReturnValue
Win32_Process.Terminate() [instance]
    Input parameters:
        UInt32 Reason
    Output parameters:
        UInt32 ReturnValue
Win32_Process.GetOwner() [instance]
    Output parameters:
        String Domain
        UInt32 ReturnValue
        String User
...
```

Unless "get methods" has a different meaning than I think it does (distinct from *calling* methods), the rest of the question seems to be dealing with something else entirely, which is the necessity of populating `Key` properties before invoking a method.  I believe this is addressed in another question of yours, [Why does WMI work through a search but not directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54892478/150605)

If what you're *really* asking is "How can I determine the minimum set of properties I need to select in order to invoke a method?", then you can accomplish that with `ManagementClass`, too.  That minimum set of properties are all properties with a [`Key` qualifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/wmisdk/key-qualifier), so you would use the [`Properties` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties) to find any property whose [`Qualifiers` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.propertydata.qualifiers) contains a qualifier with a [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.qualifierdata.name) of `"Key"`.

Consider the [`Win32_Product` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394378(v%3Dvs.85)), which represents products installed by Windows Installer and (as determined on my Windows 10 system, differing from the documentation) has **these `Key` properties**...

- `IdentifyingNumber`
- `Name`
- `Version`

Let's say you want to retrieve **these properties to display**...

- `PackageName`
- `Vendor`
- `Version`

...and then call the [`Uninstall()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa393941) for a product with a `Name` of `"Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK"`.  The following code shows three different ways to attempt this task...

1. Select **all properties** and invoke the method.
2. Select **only the properties you want to display** and invoke the method.
3. Select **the properties you want to display plus the `Key` properties** and invoke the method.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

namespace SO49798851
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Win32_Product is slow to query, so be patient!
            const string className = "Win32_Product";
            const string condition = "Name = 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK'";
            string[] allProperties = new string[] { "*" };
            string[] displayProperties = new string[] { "PackageName", "Vendor", "Version" };
            string[] keyProperties = GetKeyPropertyNames(className);
            string[] displayPlusKeyProperties = displayProperties.Union(keyProperties).ToArray();
            // When run as a non-administrator, the Uninstall() method
            // still returns 0 despite not (appearing to) do anything
            const string methodName = "Uninstall";
            object[] methodArguments = Array.Empty<object>();

            Console.WriteLine($"Key properties for class {className}: {string.Join(", ", keyProperties)}");
            Console.WriteLine();

            FindAndInvoke(className, condition, allProperties,            methodName, methodArguments);
            FindAndInvoke(className, condition, displayProperties,        methodName, methodArguments);
            FindAndInvoke(className, condition, displayPlusKeyProperties, methodName, methodArguments);
        }

        static string[] GetKeyPropertyNames(string className)
        {
            using (ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(className))
            {
                return managementClass.Properties
                    .Cast<PropertyData>()
                    .Where(
                        property => property.Qualifiers
                            .Cast<QualifierData>()
                            .Any(qualifier => string.Equals(qualifier.Name, "Key", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    )
                    .Select(property => property.Name)
                    .ToArray();
            }
        }

        static void FindAndInvoke(
            string className,
            string condition,
            string[] selectedProperties,
            string methodName,
            object[] methodArguments
        )
        {
            if (selectedProperties == null)
                selectedProperties = Array.Empty<string>();

            ObjectQuery query = new SelectQuery(className, condition, selectedProperties);
            bool allPropertiesSelected = selectedProperties.Length < 1
                || selectedProperties.Any(propertyName => propertyName == "*");

            Console.WriteLine(query.QueryString);
            Console.WriteLine(new string('=', query.QueryString.Length));

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection searchResultCollection = searcher.Get())
            {
                // ManagementObjectCollection doesn't support indexing; this is the
                // least-ugly, least-verbose way to enumerate it with an index variable
                ManagementObject[] searchResultArray = searchResultCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>().ToArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < searchResultArray.Length; i++)
                    using (ManagementObject searchResult = searchResultArray[i])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{className}[{i}].Path.RelativePath: {searchResult.Path.RelativePath}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"{className}[{i}].Properties.Count: {searchResult.Properties.Count}");
                        foreach (PropertyData property in searchResult.Properties)
                            if (allPropertiesSelected
                                    || selectedProperties.Contains(property.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                            )
                            {
                                object displayValue = property.Value ?? "<null>";

                                Console.WriteLine($"{className}[{i}].Properties[\"{property.Name}\"]: {displayValue}");
                            }

                        try
                        {
                            object methodResult = searchResult.InvokeMethod(methodName, methodArguments);

                            Console.WriteLine($"{className}[{i}].{methodName}() completed with result {methodResult}.");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{className}[{i}].{methodName}() failed with {ex}.");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and produces this output...

```
Key properties for class Win32_Product: IdentifyingNumber, Name, Version

select * from Win32_Product where Name = 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK'
===========================================================================
Win32_Product[0].Path.RelativePath: Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber="{949C0535-171C-480F-9CF4-D25C9E60FE88}",Name="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK",Version="4.8.03928"
Win32_Product[0].Properties.Count: 27
Win32_Product[0].Properties["AssignmentType"]: 1
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Caption"]: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Description"]: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK
Win32_Product[0].Properties["HelpLink"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["HelpTelephone"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["IdentifyingNumber"]: {949C0535-171C-480F-9CF4-D25C9E60FE88}
Win32_Product[0].Properties["InstallDate"]: 20191001
Win32_Product[0].Properties["InstallDate2"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["InstallLocation"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["InstallSource"]: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.8.SDK,version=4.8.3928.1\
Win32_Product[0].Properties["InstallState"]: 5
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Language"]: 1033
Win32_Product[0].Properties["LocalPackage"]: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\34d24bd7.msi
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Name"]: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK
Win32_Product[0].Properties["PackageCache"]: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\34d24bd7.msi
Win32_Product[0].Properties["PackageCode"]: {CC6C9CC4-DDCD-4C14-81E1-4007EE49D7C0}
Win32_Product[0].Properties["PackageName"]: sdk_tools48.msi
Win32_Product[0].Properties["ProductID"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["RegCompany"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["RegOwner"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["SKUNumber"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Transforms"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["URLInfoAbout"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["URLUpdateInfo"]: <null>
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Vendor"]: Microsoft Corporation
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Version"]: 4.8.03928
Win32_Product[0].Properties["WordCount"]: 0
Win32_Product[0].Uninstall() completed with result 0.

select PackageName,Vendor,Version from Win32_Product where Name = 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK'
====================================================================================================
Win32_Product[0].Path.RelativePath: 
Win32_Product[0].Properties.Count: 3
Win32_Product[0].Properties["PackageName"]: sdk_tools48.msi
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Vendor"]: Microsoft Corporation
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Version"]: 4.8.03928
Win32_Product[0].Uninstall() failed with System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, Object[] args)
   at SO49798851.Program.FindAndInvoke(String className, String condition, String[] selectedProperties, String methodName, Object[] methodArguments) in ...\Program.cs:line 90.

select PackageName,Vendor,Version,IdentifyingNumber,Name from Win32_Product where Name = 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK'
===========================================================================================================================
Win32_Product[0].Path.RelativePath: Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber="{949C0535-171C-480F-9CF4-D25C9E60FE88}",Name="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK",Version="4.8.03928"
Win32_Product[0].Properties.Count: 5
Win32_Product[0].Properties["IdentifyingNumber"]: {949C0535-171C-480F-9CF4-D25C9E60FE88}
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Name"]: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 SDK
Win32_Product[0].Properties["PackageName"]: sdk_tools48.msi
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Vendor"]: Microsoft Corporation
Win32_Product[0].Properties["Version"]: 4.8.03928
Win32_Product[0].Uninstall() completed with result 0.
```

Here are the takeaways from those three attempts...

1. Selecting all properties, of course, results in a successful method invocation, but we end up with way more properties than we wanted.
2. Selecting exactly the properties we want - but not all `Key` properties - results in a failed method invocation.

   - Notice that even though one of the `Key` properties, `Version`, was part of our query, the [`searchResult.Path` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.path) is empty in this case, a sure sign that something isn't quite right with our result object.
3. Selecting exactly the properties we want *plus* the `Key` properties results in a successful method invocation with no extraneous properties.

   - If we have a collection of properties we want (i.e. `displayProperties`) and a collection of `Key` properties (i.e. `keyProperties`), the [`Union()` LINQ method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union) makes it easy to combine them to get the minimum properties to select.