# Does ManagementClass load all of the properties?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

When using [ManagementObjectSearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) - one can search for specific properties (instead of all by `*`).

What happens when instantiating a [ManagementClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wzwcace(v=vs.110).aspx) (i.e. `new ManagementClass(someClass)`), does it load all of the properties, or is it only some sort of pointer, and will not load the properties?

.

<sub>(I'd also be happy to know what happens when using `ManagementObjectSearcher` with a `*`, does it load anything besides the properties, or is it just like specifying all of them explicitly? Logically, it should simply mean "all", but from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49798851/939213) it seems otherwise.)</sub>

Comment: Reference source for [ManagementClass](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementclass.cs,90c78a586852b14b)

Comment: Reference source for [ManagementObjectSearcher](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementobjectsearcher.cs,188a1d089eab4a48)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing happens when you instantiate it. It just [stores the query, scope and whatever else you may have specified](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementobject.cs,379). Same goes for `ManagementObjectSearcher`

When you call `.Get()`, [the query is executed against the current scope](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementobject.cs,778). As for `ManagementObjectSearcher`, the actual behavior depends on whether it's a [class enumeration or instance enumeration (e.g. a query)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementobjectsearcher.cs,330)

A query is executed and directly returns results (any properties) whereas a class enumeration will bind to the underlying WMI object [without actually loading anything](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementscope.cs,1381) until you call `.Get()` somewhere.

> does it load all of the properties, or is it only some sort of pointer

It's a [pointer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementbaseobject.cs,256) to the [CIM Object Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180678.aspx). The underlying objects are only loaded when [initialize is called with true](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementobject.cs,2578) (indicating that you want to bind to the underlying WMI object). This is what the queries are executed against.

Looking at the various calls to `Initialize()`, it seems at first glance that the objects are only bound when you're requesting properties or qualifiers. Invoking methods will not bind them.

> I'd also be happy to know what happens when using ManagementObjectSearcher with a *

Nothing until you execute the query. Which, by default, performs a [shallow enumeration](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementoptions.cs,509) on the object. This might return the qualifiers in addition to the properties, but I'm not entirely sure on that.

Also interesting (including the sibling articles): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180561.aspx

I hope this helped at all :)

Comment: So using `ManagementClass.InvokeMethod` will only invoke the method without wasting resources on accessing properties. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: As for `ManagementObjectSearcher with a *` - Yes, I meant what happens when `Get` is called. According to what I describe in [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49798851/939213) it looks like the only way to get the methods is to ask for `*` which seems to return more than just all the properties. Which doesn't seem logical.

Comment: The `InvokeMethod` itself does nothing more than connecting to the ManagementScope and getting a reference to the underlying WMI object. Of course, the manner in which you retrieve the class may or may not get everything. I don't think `ManagementObjectSearcher` will help you much if you want to be as efficient as possible. Use `new ManagementClass("Name_Of_Class")`