# Why does WMI work through a search but not directly?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi

The first of these 2 locks a BitLocked drive. The 2nd's `InvokeMethod`  throws: 'Invalid object path'. Why? They seem equivalent.

```
//Using a search:
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume WHERE DriveLetter = 'E:'");
foreach (ManagementObject classInstance1 in searcher.Get())
    classInstance1.InvokeMethod("Lock", new object[] { true }); 

//Direct:
ManagementObject classInstance2 = new ManagementObject("root\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "Win32_EncryptableVolume.DriveLetter='E:'", null);
classInstance2.InvokeMethod("Lock", new object[] { 0 });//throws: 'Invalid object path'.
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'll just assume that the correct answer is similar to what the others have mentioned but not exactly.

[The class's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secprov/win32-encryptablevolume) mentions that `DeviceID` has the following property:

> Qualifiers: Key

I assume, for lack of actual documentation, that searching for something by their **Key** returns the thing itself. While searching by something else returns a list of objects that satisfy that condition. Even if the list contains only 1 entry - it's not the object itself but rather a list.

But if someone could supply some documentation, that would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

You unfortunately can't instantiate an object using a property that isn't a key property.  A key property in WMI is a property that has the [CIM_Key qualifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/standard-wmi-qualifiers), the WMI documentation goes into further detail about the [Key Qualifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/key-qualifier).  For more information about the WMI requirement of using a full path with key to reference an object you can read the WMI documentation about [Instance Object Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/describing-an-instance-object-path).

In C#, for the particular class you specified (`Win32_EncryptableVolume`), You can only accomplish what you are trying to do by using the `ManagementObjectSearcher` as shown in your example.  This is because you are trying to get an instance based on a standard property rather than a key property.

A great utility to explore WMI is WMI Explorer 2.0.  This gives a great visual representation of WMI classes.  In this utility, Key Properties are identified with an asterisk.

https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/releases

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not calling `Get()` method. Try this:

```
ManagementObject classInstance2 = new ManagementObject("root\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "Win32_EncryptableVolume.DriveLetter='E:'", null);
classInstance2.Get();
classInstance2.InvokeMethod("Lock", new object[] { 0 });
```

Check out this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/retrieving-an-instance

Comment: I tried and got the 'Invalid object path' at the `Get` line.

Comment: Is DriveLetter the only key of the class??

Comment: No. And it actually works with DeviceID but my code doesn't know that. It knows the letter.

Comment: That is the thing. You only can retrieve the instance in a 'complete way' by searching by the key attributes. I think your best shot is to use ManagementObjectSearcher

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any link regarding that "key attribute" thing?

Comment: Yes. Look at page 348 of this book: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=e7afsJzJVCQC&pg=PA361&lpg=PA361&dq=managementobject+get+instance+constructor&source=bl&ots=r4USvpfwtT&sig=ACfU3U2xEX9J1-ryGfQrSD7PWJhBH4s0Tg&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK1tz6k9rgAhVBIrkGHQkPBWEQ6AEwCHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=managementobject%20get%20instance%20constructor&f=false